# What are common structures for firmware files?

Tags: embedded, executable, firmware

I'm a total n00b in embedded programming. Suppose I'm building a firmware using a compiler. The result of this operation is a file that will be flashed into (I guess) the flash memory of a MCU such an ARM or a AVR.

***My question is:*** *What common structures (if any) are used for such generated files containing the firmware?*

I came from desktop development and I understand that for example for Windows the compiler will most likely generate a [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) or PE+, while Unix-like systems I may get a [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and [COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF), but have no idea for embedded systems.

**I also understand that** this highly depends on many factors (Compiler, ISA, MCU vendor, OS, etc.) so I'm fine with at least one example.

---

**Update:** I will up vote all answers providing examples of used structures and will select the one I feel best surveys the state of the art.

Comment: Very broad question, not easily summarized.  Sometimes they're generally referred to as hex files, and can take a variety of formats.  See example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX  or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format) Loosely they're a listing of memory addresses and the instructions/constants at those locations.

Comment: This question is too broad. There is no defined structure for a firmware, since this is a generic term to describe self sufficient piece of code for specific architecture. Think of it as a black box - if you build it, only you know the purpose.

Comment: To the close voters: I have edited my question, can you please review your votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most tools output either an ELF, or a COFF, or something similar that can eventually boil down to a HEX/bin file.

That isn't necessarily what your target wants to see, however.  Every vendor has their own format of "firmware" files.   Sometimes they're encrypted and signed, sometimes plain text.   Sometimes there's compression, sometimes it's raw. It might be a simple file, or something complex that is more than just your program.

An integral part of doing embedded work is the build flow and system startup/booting procedure, plus getting your code onto the part. Don't underestimate the effort.

Answer (score 5):

The firmware file is the [Executable and Linkable File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), usually processed to a binary (.bin) or text represented binary (.hex).

This binary file is the exact memory that is written to the embedded flash. When you first power the board, an internal bootloader will redirect the execution to your firmware entry point, normally at the address 0x0.

From there, it is your code that is running, this is why you have a startup code (usually startup.s file) that will configure clock, stack pointer registers, vector table, load the data section to RAM (your initialized variables), clear the zero initialized section, maybe you will want to copy your code to RAM and jump to the copy to avoid running code from FLASH (can be faster on some platforms), and so on.

When running over an Operational System, all these platform choices and resources are not in control of user code, there you can only link to the OS libraries and use the provided API to do low level actions. In embedded, it is 100% user code, you access the hardware and manage its resources.

Not surprisingly, Operational Systems are booted in a similar manner as firmware, since both are there in touch with the processor, memory and I/Os.

All of that, to say: the structure of a firmware is similar to the structure of any compiled program. There's the data sections and code sections that are organized in memory during the load by the Operational System, or by the program itself when running on embedded.

One main difference is the memory addressing in the firwmare binary, usually addresses are [physical RAM address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_address), since you do not have memory mapping feature on most of micro-controllers. This is transparent to the user, the compiler will abstract it.

Other significant difference is the stack pointer, on OSs user code will not reserve memory for the stack by itself, it relays on OS for that. When on firmware, you have to do it in user code for the same reason as before, there's no middle man to manage it for you. The linker script of the compiler will reserve Stack and Heap memory accordingly configured and there will be a `stack_pointer` symbol on your .map file letting you know where it points to. You won't find it in OSs program's map files.

Comment: A bootloader is not a given or even necessary - initially execution will start at the reset vector; that may indeed be a bootloader, or it may be the application itself.

Comment: You link to the Wikipedia-page of the ELF format which is typically **not** used as firmware file. And firmware does not require an OS or a bootloader. Also there is no requirement the firmware file is exactly an image of the Flash (in case there **is** Flash).

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately the data written to the ROM is normally just the code and constant data from which your application is composed, and therefore has no structure other than perhaps being segmented into code and data, and possibly custom segments if you have created them.  The structure in this sense is defined by the linker script or configuration used to build the code.  The file containing this code/data may be raw binary, or an encoded binary format such as Intel Hex or Motorola S-Record for example.

Typically also your toolchain will generate an object code file that contains not only the code/data, but also symbolic and debug information for use by a debugger.  In this case when the debugger runs, it loads the code to the target (as in the binary file case above) and the symbol/debug information to the host to allow source level debugging.  These files may be in a proprietary object file format specific to the toolchain, but are often standard "open" formats such as ELF.  However strictly the meta-data components of an object file are not part of the *firmware* since they are not loaded on the target.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently run across another firmware format not listed here. It's a binary format, might be called ".EEP" but might not. I think it is used by NXP. I've seen it used for ARM THUMB2 and for mystery stuff that may be a DSP/BSP.

All the following are 32-bit values, all stored in reverse endian *except* for CAFEBABE (so... BEBAFECA?):

```
CAFEBABE 
length_in_16_bit_words(yes, 16-bit...?!)
base_addr 
CRC32 
length*2 bytes of data
FFFF (optional filler if the length is an odd number)
```

If there are more data blocks:

```
length 
base
checksum that is not a CRC but something bizarre
data
FFFF (optional filler if the length is an odd number)

...
```

When no more data blocks remain:

```
length == 0
base == 0
checksum that is not a CRC but something bizarre
```

Then all of that is repeated for another memory bank/device.